# Rollback TFS merge partially

Tags: version-control, tfs, branching-and-merging

I saw similar question in stack overflow but its not the same. I need rollback TFS merge partially

I was doing merging two branches in TFS. I taken my test system branch & merged with the other branch. The check in count was more than 100 & I handled conflicts manually(More than 50 files). Its now at a level for client to show demo.

But now my problem is my manager telling the merge should happen things(change sets) only moved to production. I have multiple change sets in test branch but all merged to single change set in the other branch. Now i need to Undo merging on some of the change sets from test to the other branch.

The rollbacking on test those change sets & merging them again won't work since that branch when testing passed other things will move to production.

So any way to get it done other than restarting from begining?

Thanks
Binesh Nambiar C

Answer (score 1):

I understand your scenario as, for example, you merged changeset21(which contains changeset1, changeset10, and changeset20) to "Other Branch". And now, you would like to merge only changeset1 and want to rollback changeset10 and changeset20.

You need to:

1. Rollback the changeset21 that is merged to "Other Branch". Via doing this, all changes changeset21 contains are rolled back. Check in the rollback changes.
2. Right-click the Test branch in the Solution Explorer -> Branching and Merging -> Merge -> Selected Changesets.
3. Then select changesets you want to merge to "Other Branch".

[image]

Comment: Ya, I did in the same way. I did undo checkout them checked in. Then rollbacked the undo checkout and checked in. Then moved only the rollbacked things in other branch.

Comment: @BineshNambiarC, as you don't want changes merged to the "other" branch, you need to do rollback pending changes option on the "other" branch.